# Backup with duplicity on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: backup, cloud, duplicity

I have already set a backup routine that backups all my files to Amazon S3 using duplicity. I would like to create a similar backup routine with Google Cloud Storage. Is it possible to get duplicity to work with GCS?

Answer (score 8):

There is now (since 2013-07-19 - version 0.6.22) support to use Google Cloud Storage directly in duplicity.

You should use `gsutil config -a` to create a `~/.boto` config file. And then you can use duplicity like this:

```
duplicity local_dir gs://yourbucket
```

Also of note is that only the old authentication mechanism is supported. You should enable "Interoperable Access" from your [Google Storage Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/#:storage).

Detailed steps on [http://www.willdurness.com/back-up-your-vm-to-google-cloud-storage-using-duplicity](https://web.archive.org/web/20140818044758/http://www.willdurness.com/back-up-your-vm-to-google-cloud-storage-using-duplicity).

Comment: That "detailed steps" link now 404s :(

Answer (score 7):

- As of August 2012, Duplicity *does not* support Google Cloud Storage (GCS); a [search of the *duplicity-talk* mailing list archives](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=google&submit=Search!&idxname=duplicity-talk&max=20&result=normal&sort=date%3Alate) shows that there has been no discussion, even at a wishlist stage, of adding such support.

  - Google Docs is supported, but that API is totally different from GCS.
  - [Wishlist bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1030868) filed recently
- While the Python [*boto*](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/index.html) module used as a back-end by Duplicity to provide S3 support also supports GCS, adding GCS support to duplicity would require non-trivial modifications to its code; the [S3](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html) and [GCS](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/gs.html) APIs are not identical.

  - If anyone wants to give adding GCS support a go, it would be simplest to start with and modify the `_boto_single.py` file which provides the backend for single-threaded S3 transactions.
- That GCS isn't widely supported shouldn't come as a surprise. It is nowhere near as universal as S3; for example, you must register as a developer with Google and the service is still considered part of the "beta" Google Labs.

  - The *only* backup solution I could find supporting GCS is *Zmanda* (commercial).
  - As Google rolls out GCS on a wider basis--beyond just developers--I think we should start seeing support for it in FOSS apps.
- **For now**, to use Duplicity with GCS, you must either backup to S3 and then use Google's `gsutil` tool to sync S3 with GCS, as Jorge's answer indicates; alternately, you could use Duplicity to backup locally and then sync that with GCS using `gsutil`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a partial-answer that might help the next person:

So far it seems that copying things to Google Drive/Docs is supported:

```
duplicity localdir gdocs://username:password@gmail.com/remotedir/
```

However this is different from Google Cloud Storage. I *think* this should be doable since duplicity and [gsutil](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) both use boto, but I'm not sure if this requires work to be done in duplicity itself though.

As a work around until you sort this, you can certainly copy directly from the s3 to the GCS buckets:

```
gsutil -m cp -R s3://yourbucket gs://yourbucket
```

Answer (score 2):

Version v0.6.22 (2013/08/22) of Duplicity added Google Cloud Storage support.

Answer (score 2):

`deja-dup` 34.1 (duplicity's GUI) now has "experimental support for Google Cloud Storage" (https://launchpad.net/deja-dup/+milestone/34.1)

(I tried enabling interoperability for HMAC authentication on my GCS buckets and specifying an S3 Bucket in earlier versions of Deja-Dup - similar to how `duplicity` does it - but to no avail)