# Offsite Backup Software for Ubuntu

Tags: backup

Is there a backup solution for Ubuntu that allows you to schedule backups, enable encryption of sensitive personal data and stores your backups offsite in the a cloud storage account? Example of this solution is Acronis. Looking to get off of Windows for my personal PC, but I need a backup strategy that is not a file sync like Google Drive, DropBox or OneDrive, also not interested in building a machine to be backup server.  Thank you.

Comment: Also see http://blog.domenech.org/2013/01/backing-up-ubuntu-using-deja-dup-backup-and-aws-s3.html and http://askubuntu.com/questions/436503/deja-dup-google-drive-support

Answer (score 1):

Borg Backup will split your data into encrypted chunks.

https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

It also can create versioned, deduplicated archives all inside one backup repository. It's a little tricky to get started with (it's a command line tool) but it's included in the Ubuntu repositories. If you use a good password and upload your repository to Dropbox or wherever, then nobody but you knows what's in it. Even the file names are changed to block ID names.

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install borgbackup
```